# Convert PDE from cartesian to cylindrical

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to convert the Navier-Stokes relation from cartesian to cylindrical.

I have $3$ relations:

$$\mu \left(\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v_y}{\partial x} \right) = \tau_{xy} = \tau_{yx};$$
$$\mu \left(\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial z}  + \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial y} \right) = \tau_{yz}= \tau_{zy} ;$$
$$\mu \left(\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial z}  + \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial x} \right) = \tau_{zx}= \tau_{xz} .$$

And I know the solutions are:

$$\mu \left[r\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(\frac{v_{\theta}}{r} \right) + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial \theta} \right] = \tau_{r \theta} = \tau_{\theta r};$$
$$\mu \left(\frac{\partial v_{\theta}}{\partial z} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial \theta} \right) = \tau_{\theta z} = \tau_{z \theta};$$
$$\mu \left(\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r}  + \frac{\partial v_r}{\partial z} \right) = \tau_{zr}= \tau_{rz} .$$

I am having trouble seeing how these can be derived from the cartesian equations.

Could someone help explain one of these derivations so that it would help me to understand?

Comment: Does anyone know a method to convert this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you please format this using mathJax (see FAQ) as it would greatly improve readability? Regards

Comment: Thank you for converting. Can anyone help witht his?

Comment: What are $v_x$, $v_y$ and $v_z$? Are they the partial derivatives of $v$ with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$ (respectively)?

Comment: You are right, they are the partials

Comment: Is $\tau_{xy}$ the second derivative of $\tau$?

Comment: no it is not, just in the direction of

Comment: @CameronWilliams Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Ben Are you aware of the following relationships?

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \cos\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r} -\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta},$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{\cos\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$$

Comment: @Ben you can get these relationships from $x = r\cos\theta$, $y = r\sin\theta$, $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ while making use of the multivariable chain rule.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, I am not quite following. I had the relations:  d/dx = d/dr*dr/dx + d/dtheta(dtheta/dx)

Comment: @Ben you're correct. But to evaluate $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ and similarly for $\theta$, you have to use the above equations I gave you. $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ so $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \dfrac{x}{r} = \cos\theta$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams So shouldn't it be d/dr(cos(theta)) and not cos(theta)d/dr?

Comment: @Ben the order of those two doesn't matter.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Is there anyway you could carry one of these out to completion? Then I could do the other 2 myself

Comment: @Ben sure thing. I'll post it as a solution when I'm done.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you, I really appreciate this!

Comment: @Ben should the $y$ derivative in your fourth equation actually be an $r$ derivative?

Comment: yes. sorry my mistake

Comment: @Ben since $v_i$ is not a partial derivative, what I did was wrong and I need to redo everything. I'll sketch it later and add it as an answer. By the way you should delete your "answer" below.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Ok thank you for doing this. I'm sorry for the confusion.